# TypeError: cannot read property 'css' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set the minimum-height of my div element by referring to its class name but it comes back with an error: **TypeError: cannot read property 'css' of null**.

**HTML element**:

```
<div class="container contentContainer" id="topContainer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="topRow">
                <p class="bold">Please scroll down for more information </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("contentContainer");
        alert(x);
        if(x != null)
        {
            $(".contentContainer").css('min-height',$(window).height());
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions as to why am I getting this error? Kindly let me know.

The problem occurs when I include my external javascript file:

```
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/monthly.js"></script> -->
```

Comment: Have you added a script tag with jQuery?

Comment: Yes I did. Is that incorrect?

Comment: jQuery is apparently not loaded, as you have had to remove the `$(function () {...}` to get your code to work.

Comment: My code does not give any errors when I uncomment the $(function() .. {} but it doesn't work the way I expect it to i.e. set the minimum height.

Comment: Can you post your full code? And have you tried it with a document.ready()?

Comment: I have added the code on JsFiddle showing the same'ish error.

Comment: Yeah, `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. [After adding jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/9khm3tw7/) there's no errors.

Comment: It looks fine with the `$(function(..` http://jsfiddle.net/jjLxwq6c/

Comment: Geez. Everyone here is overlooking the *simplest* error.

Comment: @minseong You mean the missing jQuery link at the fiddle? As far as I can understand, OP has the issue in their original production code, the fiddle was created afterwards.

Comment: @Teemu I see that now, they could at least provide an apt fiddle.

Comment: @TheNewbie Unless any of the loaded plugins won't conflict with jQuery and/or somehow override `$`, please try to link the jQuery  from the address linked in ThomasBormans'es answer.

Comment: I've tried including both jQuery version 1.x.x. and 2.x.x. etc and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're loading jQuery and Bootstrap at the same time and they both clobber the `$` symbol; to use only jQuery you would use the canonical name:

```
jQuery(".contentContainer")
    .css('min-height', jQuery(window).height());
```

Or, use a wrapper:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".contentContainer").css('min-height',$(window).height());
});
```

Comment: I've included the latest jQuery version using     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>.. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: @TheNewbie Then it's not loaded in the right place; make sure it's loaded *above* the `<script>` tag you have your code in.

Comment: Yes it is above the script tag I have my code in. I'll update my javascript to show you the whole code of my script.

Comment: @TheNewbie It's Bootstrap that's causing the issue, not jQuery.

Comment: @Jack I'm betting that's the problem. +1

Comment: And that was exactly right. I changed the '$' to 'jQuery' and it worked finally :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the jQuery syntax.

```
$(window).height();
```

You will need to include jQuery or use the native JavaScript version:

```
window.innerHeight;
```

In order to use jQuery, you will need to include the [jQuery library](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js)

Comment: How is this related to OP's problem?

Comment: At first sight, it looked like he was using the jQuery syntax which was giving errors.

Answer (score 0):

You were getting the error on the JSFiddle because you hadn't included jQuery.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pzrc219/6/)

On the left nav-bar, there is a section which says "**Frameworks & Extensions**". You need to select

```
jQuery (edge)
```

Or any jQuery version from that drop-down list.

[image: JSFiddle side-bar]

Because you hadn't included jQuery, the `$` constructor didn't exist, so the error

```
TypeError: cannot read property 'css' of null.
```

was thrown because you were trying to access a property of a non-existent (null) object.

Comment: But I did include jQuery.     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @TheNewbie Not in your JSFiddle, you don't.

Comment: If `$` doesn't exist, you would get a reference error, not a type error.

Comment: @Ja͢ck Yeah, that's what I don't understand. I never got any type errors, only a reference error on the OP's fiddle.

Comment: It seems that Bootstrap is kicking up the stink.

Comment: Yeah I did not include it in my JsFiddle but I am talking about my website code. Its included there and I've just added that to my javascript code area in my question. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("contentContainer");
```

Returns an array of elements having that class. Access the required element as you would in a normal array.

```
x[0]     //The first element, if there is any.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type $ [ENTER] on your browser console do you get something like

```
function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)
```

If the selector $('.contentContainer') returns null and not an object containing function css, maybe $ is not referencing to jQuery or has been changed beetween where you include jquery.js and the code you are trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

If your error is occurring in the use of bootstrap-dialog, comment out the following line of code in the bootstrap-dialog.js file:

$backdrop.css('z-index', zIndexBackdrop + (dialogCount - 1) * 20);

This stops the "TypeError: cannot read property 'css' of null" error.

If your error is not occurring in the use of bootstrap-dialog, open the relevant js file, then comment out all of the css file references in it and re-run the web page. It should run successfully. Then uncomment the lines of code one by one and re-test the page until it breaks again. This will eventually lead you to the villain line of code, then you can comment it out and avoid this error going forward.