# Overiride image icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a component on one of my pages for which I cannot edit the code, there is a icon on the page which I wish to override can anyone help me on how to do that. Thanks!

```
.classname {
    background: transparent url(/img/vote/promotebg_on.png ) no-repeat scroll center top;
}
```

Comment: Just change the png with photoshop ???  or make a new rule setting your img as the new background ?? Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you want to override it when you cannot edit source, but maybe !important notation will be useful for you.

```
.classname {
    background: transparent url(/img/vote/promotebg_on.png ) no-repeat scroll center top !important;
}
```

Comment: I know the class name from the source, my question was if I could remove the existing properties and create new ones for that particular class onload.

Comment: @cartman if you can't edit the code you can't remove those properties, it's better if you keep them and create override just the bg-image on your css

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.classname').css("background-image", "newimage.png");
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Ideahome:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of null, I get the above error when I try to override it.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/ try and do it using attribute instaed of css

Comment: @cartman Are you [using bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887933/typeerror-cannot-read-property-css-of-null)?